# What is "Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains)"

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I am new in Maven and tried creating Maven project using command line. 
When I run `mvn archetype:generate` from the command line
The first thing after completion of all processes were:

```
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains)
```

I know we can skip these by pressing an Enter. But I really wanted to know what exactly these lines are? I googled but there is no crisp and simple answer given.
My questions are:

1. Why and how to choose a number, how its related to filter (as filter and number are in OR).
2. We can skip these then why it is given by Maven..
3. Why this number **630** specifically is displayed.
4. Is there any default value is assigned when we skip these lines by pressing Enter.[This is more important]

Looking for sharp and crisp answer or link.

Update : These are the few lines just before "choose a number.." appears..

```
1380: remote -> tr.com.lucidcode:kite-archetype (A Maven Archetype that allows u
sers to create a Fresh Kite project)
1381: remote -> uk.ac.rdg.resc:edal-ncwms-based-webapp (-)
1382: remote -> uk.co.nemstix:basic-javaee7-archetype (A basic Java EE7 Maven ar
chetype)
1383: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-maven-project (-)
1384: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-command (-)
1385: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-dbconnector (-)
1386: remote -> us.fatehi:schemacrawler-archetype-plugin-lint (-)
**Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive co
ntains): 630:**
Choose org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart version:
1: 1.0-alpha-1
2: 1.0-alpha-2
3: 1.0-alpha-3
4: 1.0-alpha-4
5: 1.0
6: 1.1
Choose a number: 6:
```

Comment: It would be important to understand what the output before this message was, please add it. also possibly interesting: your maven version (`mvn -v`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newbie: maven archetype:generate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194257/newbie-maven-archetypegenerate)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Command mvn archetype:generate:**

Generates a new project from an archetype, or updates the actual project if using a partial archetype. If the project is fully generated, it is generated in a directory corresponding to its artifactId. If the project is updated with a partial archetype, it is done in the current directory.

There are more then 1000 archetype are available in Maven, when ever you select any one of them it will generate and sample Maven project for you, which will include the dependencies in pom.xml by default.

630 is by default and basically for : **remote -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart**

Comment: so where I can find the list of archetype?

Comment: This list is useful one but i cant find the archetype mentioned here (https://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/developing-plugins/plugin-development.html)

Comment: Default is  1785 for now